# JQuery Mobile Fixed header and Footer Bar disappears when scrolling

Tags: jquery, ajax

JQuery Mobile Fixed header and Footer Bar disappears when scrolling and then it appear again when scrolling stops. i'm testing with ripple emulator

```
<div id="tv_links" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#business" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Business News </a>

                <li><a href="#sportsnews" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Sports News </a>

                    <li>
<a href="#weather_update" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Weather </a>

                        <li>
<a href="#interactive" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Get Live </a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your li tags are not closed!
Did you try closing them?